# Adding multiple images to a table in .NetCore using C# and html

Tags: c#, html, image, asp.net-core

I am working on my senior project for college. I am having a lot of trouble adding multiple images to this database/table in my project. I followed this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get all my stuff up and running, it looks just like it except I have more information. I am making a movie rental application and my movies need images to go with them in the database. I have been trying so much and nothing that I find seems to fit into what I have. Here are more details that you might want in order to help me:

1. I set my datatype from Images to "string" get; set;
2. I have added an image folder with all images in it to my www.root
3. [image: This is a picture of my database]
4. [image: This is my Create.chtml]

I hope someone can help me with this, I feel like there is something really simple im not grasping.
Thank you!

Comment: Okay, there are a few questions to help us to help you:
1º This is a image source?
2º Can you give us a string example from this property?
3º HAve you already verified the property spelling?

Comment: Well im not too experienced with programming to begin with. I barley know what any of this means. But I will try my best. I need to get these images in my root folder into this table im assuming I can use a source. The database is seeded and everything else is in there except the pictures. I was told I could input the pictures through HTML into the project but I don't know how the program will know what pictures go where. I used the string data type for my images. Not sure if that was a good move or not. Thank you. Im sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: public string Image {get; set;}

Comment: Okay, dont worry! I Will try to help you!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's go! I'll try to help!

You can access root folder just like `localhost:5050/images/image.png`.

Then, check the root folder and create a folder named as `image` and a image inside named as `image.png`;

Now, configure the razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <img src="@Model.Image" style="width: 50px;height: 50px" />
</div>
```

`@Model.Image` has to be `'/images/image.png'` or `'images/image.png'`

Hope this can give you some light!

Comment: Thank you! This does help. Also, I am just confused on how I get multiple images. I need 8 images in my database. How can I do that?

Comment: If it answer you please check as correct! So When you has multiple images, just add then in the database, all the correct paths; The cursor you has already put in the code, to load all this information;

You read the cursor and put the data in those lines, the same with images.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way you are doing this is not going to work very well. This, indeed, works for one image, but for several images, you need several things.

First, you need an extra EF entity for images, which have an uri property of either data type string or Uri and a MovieId property of the data type used in the movie entity on it's Id property. You might also need a navigation property of type Movie.

In the Movie entity, you replace the string Images with a collection (ICollecion) of images (using the just-created entity.

Now, in your Razor, you can loop over the images and access them in the ~/images directory.